# How to limit and randomize the web output?

Tags: python, random, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way where I can limit a website generaot output and make the output more randomize since it outputs the name alphabetically. I tried to use limit and randomize i, but it doesn't seem to work

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import json
import requests
import validators
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import numpy as np
import random 
import whois
import pandas as pd
import itertools

Combined = open("dictionaries/Combined.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
Example = open("dictionaries/examples.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")

with open("dictionaries/Combined.txt") as i:
    Test = [line.rstrip() for line in i]
```

This is what's inside the `Combined.txt`

[image: Combined text file]

```
delimeters = ['','-', '.']

output_count = 100
web = 'web'
suffix = 'co.id'
for x in range(output_count):
    output = []
    for combo in itertools.combinations(Test, 2):
        out = ''
        for i, d in enumerate(delimeters):
            out = d.join(combo)
            out = delimeters[i-1].join([out, web])
            addr = '.'.join([out, suffix])
            output.append(random.choice(out))
            Example.write(addr+'\n')

with open("dictionaries/examples.txt") as f:
websamples = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

This is the output that i get.

```
websamples
```

[image: websamples]

[image: Websamples 2]

As you see at the image, the web generator outputs too many web domain generator it doesn't even show the rest of the output in Jupyter Notebook. Is there a way where the web domain generator doesn't output the web alphabetically and mix it up and limits the number of outputs that I want? for example i want to limit it to just a 100 with randomize outputs instead of outputting possible combination domain name and outputs it alphabetically

Thanks

Comment: Sure... we can just add a random chooser in there... Is that all?

Comment: yep, i want to limit the number of outputs to just 100, so to do that i tried to give it a range by adding this in the code `output_count = 100` `output = []` but it doesn't seem to work and I also mixed it up with this line `output.append(random.choice(out))` so that within that 100 outputs, the web generator name doesn't output it alphabetically. @Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the Test list of course that should generate 100 addresses as randomly put together as possible.

Try this:

```
import random
#Test = ['auth', 'access', 'account', 'admin', 'agree', 'blue', 'business', 'cdn', 'cl', 'click', 'confirm', 'download', 'enroll', 'find', 'group', 'install', 'login', 'mobile', 'my', 'online', 'pay', 'portal', 'register']
delimeters = ['','-', '.']
web, suffix = 'web', 'co.id'
output = []
for i in range(100):
    prefix = random.choice(delimeters).join([random.choice(Test), random.choice(Test)])
    out = random.choice(delimeters).join([prefix, web])
    addr = '.'.join([out, suffix])
    output.append(addr)
    Example.write(addr+'\n')
```

OUTPUT:

```
  [
    "blue.auth.web.co.id",
    "pay.my-web.co.id",
    "click.install-web.co.id",
    "clickgroupweb.co.id",
    "businessinstallweb.co.id",
    "portal.install.web.co.id",
    "click.online-web.co.id",
    "accesscl.web.co.id",
    "admin-blue-web.co.id",
    "register-group.web.co.id",
    "business-enroll-web.co.id",
    "download-payweb.co.id",
    "portal.cl-web.co.id",
    "paybusiness.web.co.id",
    "business.click-web.co.id",
    "downloadblue-web.co.id",
    "businesslogin-web.co.id",
    "my.admin.web.co.id",
    "login.my.web.co.id",
    "mobileonlineweb.co.id",
    "cl-login.web.co.id",
    "business.account.web.co.id",
    "pay.click.web.co.id",
    "group.enrollweb.co.id",
    "agreecdn.web.co.id",
    "enroll-auth.web.co.id",
    "confirm.confirmweb.co.id",
    "account.register.web.co.id",
    "admincl.web.co.id",
    "clickmobile-web.co.id",
    "registerdownload.web.co.id",
    "download.admin.web.co.id",
    "business.my-web.co.id",
    "account-download-web.co.id",
    "auth-account.web.co.id",
    "login-clickweb.co.id",
    "businessregister.web.co.id",
    "mobile.accountweb.co.id",
    "cl.groupweb.co.id",
    "payagree-web.co.id",
    "portal-cdnweb.co.id",
    "online.my-web.co.id",
    "pay-cdnweb.co.id",
    "accountgroupweb.co.id",
    "pay.confirmweb.co.id",
    "confirm.cl-web.co.id",
    "group-access-web.co.id",
    "install-payweb.co.id",
    "enroll.pay.web.co.id",
    "business.mobileweb.co.id",
    "accessclickweb.co.id",
    "login.onlineweb.co.id",
    "clickdownload-web.co.id",
    "blueinstall.web.co.id",
    "installlogin-web.co.id",
    "portalloginweb.co.id",
    "myconfirmweb.co.id",
    "admin-authweb.co.id",
    "portal-admin-web.co.id",
    "cl.my-web.co.id",
    "admin.register.web.co.id",
    "auth-blueweb.co.id",
    "admin.blueweb.co.id",
    "my-accountweb.co.id",
    "auth.installweb.co.id",
    "portal-install-web.co.id",
    "downloadmobile-web.co.id",
    "online.blue.web.co.id",
    "blue.find.web.co.id",
    "group-blueweb.co.id",
    "adminclickweb.co.id",
    "cdnconfirm.web.co.id",
    "agree-click.web.co.id",
    "cl.enroll.web.co.id",
    "login.admin-web.co.id",
    "groupbusinessweb.co.id",
    "agree.cdn-web.co.id",
    "my-groupweb.co.id",
    "clagree.web.co.id",
    "click.authweb.co.id",
    "enrollfind.web.co.id",
    "find-findweb.co.id",
    "click-cdn-web.co.id",
    "cdnagree.web.co.id",
    "loginmobileweb.co.id",
    "paybusiness-web.co.id",
    "online.install-web.co.id",
    "my-clweb.co.id",
    "group-install.web.co.id",
    "findenrollweb.co.id",
    "cl-accessweb.co.id",
    "register.click.web.co.id",
    "register-business.web.co.id",
    "portal-account.web.co.id",
    "admin-accessweb.co.id",
    "confirmloginweb.co.id",
    "loginclick.web.co.id",
    "agree-group-web.co.id",
    "click-group.web.co.id",
    "confirm-enroll.web.co.id"
  ]
```

Comment: This one is much simpler to understand, and also with this code i can do a more randomize TLD or suffix thx!

Comment: Yah this question was relatively straight forward... If this is what you wanted all along then we did a lot of unnecessary work.  I thought you wanted every single permutation of combinations in the Test list with different delimeters between alll of them...

Comment: i did want that at first, but it ended up taking to much time to check and process whether the website exists or not @Alexander.

Comment: @Tsukuru  all good :)

Comment: Once again thx for the help! I managed to improve it even further so that the web domain has more characters in and it's based on the number of words I want in the domain. @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Using the built in `random` library is going to be your friend here. For example if you want to select 100 random elements from a list you can use the `random.sample` function as demonstrated below:

```
nums = list(range(1000))
random_nums = random.sample(nums, 100)
print(random_nums)
```

You can read more about this function here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample